# How can I find matching values in two arrays and print then?

Tags: c

How can I find matching values in two arrays and print then?

I need to make a program in c that the user should enter 10 integers greater than zero and store them in an array. Then the user must enter 10 more integer numerical values greater than zero and store them in another array. The program should display all the values that are part of both arrays, but I can't find a way to do this without making modular code, and I don't want to do this.
Can someone help me?

I tried to use this code but it didn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int vetor[10], vetor2[10], vetor3[10];
    int i, j , k = 0;

    printf("Digite 10 números inteiros e maiores que zero:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    {       
        printf("Número %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);

    }while (vetor[i] <=0 );
    }   

    printf("\n\nDigite mais 10 números inteiros e maiores que zero:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    {       
        printf("Número %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor2[i]);

    }while (vetor2[i] <=0 );
    }   
    
    printf("\nValores digitados no vetor 1:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n%d ", vetor[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nValores digitados no vetor 2:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n%d ", vetor2[i]);
    }
    
    if (vetor[i] == vetor2[i]) {
            vetor3[j] = vetor[1];
            j++;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("\n\nValores que fazem parte nos dois vetores:\n");
        printf("\n%d ", vetor3[j]);
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

@pmacfarlane i make some changes in the code, i don't know if this is what you want, because i didnt understand correctly what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
int vetor[10], vetor2[10], vetor3[10];
int i, j = 0;

printf("Enter 10 integers numbers greater than zero:\n");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    {
        printf("Number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);

    }
    while (vetor[i] <= 0);
}

printf("\n\nEnter 10 more integers numbers greater than zero:\n");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    {
        printf("Número %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor2[i]);

    }
    while (vetor2[i] <= 0)
        ;
}

printf("\nValues entered in vector 1:\n");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("\n%d ", vetor[i]);
}

printf("\n\nValues entered in vector 2:\n");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("\n%d ", vetor2[i]);
}


if (vetor[i] == vetor2[i]) {
   
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n\nValues that are present in both arrays:\n");
        printf("\n%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: _I can't find a way to do this without making modular code, and I don't want to do this._ What does this mean? Modular code is something you should strive for, not avoid.

Comment: Loop through the first array, inside, loop through the second array. Check if a1[i]==a2[j] , then print

Comment: The naive approach is to compare each value in one array with all the others in the 2nd array. To do that you'll need a nested loop. Also recommend hardcoding both array for debugging purposes, you'll save a whole lot of time by not having to type in 20 numbers each iteration. Then bring back the user input once your algorithm is working.

Comment: Your code would be easier to understand if you indented it properly. It is currently very misleading (and probably broken). e.g. look at your very first `for` loop, and then track the braces `{`. What does this code even do?

Comment: Also, please enable more warnings on your compiler. For gcc you can use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. At the very least, your variable `j` is not initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result of properly indenting your code. (I used `indent -kr` on Linux, then added a few newlines):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int vetor[10], vetor2[10], vetor3[10];
    int i, j, k = 0;

    printf("Digite 10 números inteiros e maiores que zero:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        {
            printf("Número %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
        }

        while (vetor[i] <= 0)
            ;
    }

    printf("\n\nDigite mais 10 números inteiros e maiores que zero:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        {
            printf("Número %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &vetor2[i]);
        }

        while (vetor2[i] <= 0)
            ;
    }

    printf("\nValores digitados no vetor 1:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n%d ", vetor[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nValores digitados no vetor 2:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n%d ", vetor2[i]);
    }

    if (vetor[i] == vetor2[i]) {
        vetor3[j] = vetor[1];
        j++;
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            printf("\n\nValores que fazem parte nos dois vetores:\n");
            printf("\n%d ", vetor3[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You have a weird extra level of `{}` in the body of your first two `for` loops. Are those meant to be `do ... while()` inside there?

Both of your `for` loops that read in the arrays will, on detecting a number that is `<= 0`, enter an infinite loop. I suspect that is not what you want.

After your second loop that prints the arrays, you have `if (vetor[i] == vetor2[i])`. At this point, `i` is `10`, and so you are indexing your arrays out of bounds. This invokes undefined behaviour.

If the undefined behaviour happens to result in the `if` evaluating true, you then do `vetor3[j] = vetor[1];`. But `j` is not initialised at this point. This also invokes undefined behaviour. I'm not sure why you want `vetor[1]` either.

You then run a loop from `0` to `j`, printing numbers from `vetor3[]`, even though you only ever possibly set one member of that array.

I'd recommend using an editor that can format your code for you, and running your compiler with more warnings enabled.

Comment: the extra level of `{}` is the do, i just didn't write it.
the `<= 0` is to not have numbers below or equal to zero.
`vetor[1]` is an error, i want to say `vetor[i]`, do you know how to find and print the common elements from the arrays `vetor[10]` and `vetor2[10]?

Comment: `vetor[i]` invokes undefined behaviour because `i` is `10` here. "I just didn't write it" - not sure how to respond to that. We can only debug the code you give us. Fix all the bugs I mentioned (and any others, e.g. what is `k`?) Yes, I (and most people who watch the C tag) do know how to find and print the common numbers, but you need to at least give us some sane code to work with. And please, please, indent your code sensibly.

Comment: ok, i am a beginner programmer maybe that is why you don't understand my code right, and I don't speak English very well, and part of my code is in Portuguese. I will try to arumar what you asked and send the code again

Comment: Your English is excellent. The problems are in the code.

Comment: i dont understand what exactly you want to  me change in the code, you ask before what does this code even do, the code was to have two arrays of 10 numbers that the user would add in each, and identify the numbers that have in the two arrays and show to the user which ones they are.

Comment: @luuz I thought I explained most of it in my answer. Fix the undefined behaviour, logic errors, and compiler warnings, would be a good start. I know what your code is meant to do. I'm not going to write it for you.

Comment: i make an edit in my post with a change in my code